# Determine $\ker(f)$, if $f$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ and the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{6} = \{\bar{0}, \ldots,\bar{4}, \bar{5}\}$.

1.Define $f: \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}_6$ by $f(m) =\overline{4m} \in \mathbb{Z}_6$ for all $m∈\mathbb{Z}.$ Is $f$ a ring homomorphism?

2. Determine $\ker(f)$ explicitly, if $f$ is a ring homomorphism.
3. Determine $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ explicitly, if $f$ is a ring homomorphism.

**My attempt:** After many trials and errors, I have found that $f$ is a ring homomorphism, and that's all. I don't know what to do for the next two questions except for the definition. Please I don't need the answer. I need to understand the concept completely. So any long details would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a ring homomorphism? It doesn't send $1$ to $1$...

Comment: @CameronWilliams It is not necessary for a ring homomorphism. But it should send $0$ to $0$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Really? The definition I've seen does require that. Edit: seems different people have different conventions here.

Comment: It really depends on whether or not you require a ring to have a multiplicative identity.  Not everyone does.

Comment: @CameronWilliams For example consider the zero map between 2 rings.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Yeah it seems some people have different definitions here. I've always understood rings to have a multiplicative identity but if you don't make that assumption, my comment is silly.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Even when the 2 rings have multiplicative identities a homomorphism between those two does not require sending $1$ to $1$. For eg: the zero map between $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and itself.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Some authors disagree, e.g. Lang insists $1$ go to $1$.

Comment: @Cameron Williams But doesn't this example contradict it?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Depending on what your definition is for a ring homomorphism. Hungerford doesn't require it apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of the homomorphism is the set of all elements that are sent to $0$. Since the homomorphism is mapping $m$ to $4m$ and an element $\overline{n}\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ is $0$ when $n$ is divisible by $6$, the kernel is the set of all integers $m$ such that $4m$ is divisible by $6$. An integer is divisible by $6$ if and only if it is divisible by $2$ and $3$. $4m$ is divisible by $2$ for all $m$, and $4m$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $m$ is divisible by $3$. Thus the kernel consists of all multiples of $3$, or in other words $3\mathbb{Z}$.

The image of $f$ is the set of all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ that occur as a value of $f$ for some input $m$. Thus we must consider which remainders modulo $6$ we obtain from integers of the form $4m$. If $m$ is divisible by $6$ or has a remainder of $3$ then $f(m)=\overline{0}$. If $m$ has a remainder of $1$ or $4$ then $f(m)=\overline{4}$. Finally, if $m$ has a remainder of $2$ or $5$ then $f(m)=\overline{2}$. Having considered all cases we conclude that the image is $\{\overline{0},\overline{2},\overline{4}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For 2) According to the definition ker $f$ must be the integers which makes $0$ as the image. To make $0, 4m$ must be a multiple of $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\overline{4m}=\overline 0$, or in other words $6|4m$.

It's not hard to see that $6|4m\iff 3|m$. Hence $3\Bbb Z$ is $\ker f$.

Now, if $m\equiv 1\pmod 3$, $m=3k+1$, and $4m=12k+4\equiv 4\pmod 6$.  If $m\equiv 2\pmod 4$, then $m=3n+2$ and $4m=12n+8\equiv2\pmod3$.  Hence $\text{Im }f=\{\overline 0,\overline 2, \overline 4\}$.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong here, but how did you get $6|4m \iff 3|m$? Wouldn't that be $3|2m$?

Comment: No, $6|4m$ implies that $3|4m$ and since $3\nmid4$ we must have $3|m$.

Comment: Or $6|4m$ implies $3|2m$ as you state, and $3\nmid2$ implies $3|m$.

Comment: Try writing out $f(0), f(1), f(2)$ etc.  This should help your understanding.